# Bash - pipe to variable and file

Tags: bash, tee

In the simplified example bellow, "anything" is correctly echoed from the $S" variable into "S.gz" file. However, the variable loses its value out of the pipe stream:

```
echo 'anything' | tee >(read S | gzip >S.gz)
zcat S.gz
echo '$S='"$S"
```

It echoes:

```
anything
$S=
```

The intended output is:

```
anything
$S=anything
```

Another way, same unfortunate output:

```
echo 'anything' | tee >(read S) | gzip >S.gz
zcat S.gz
echo '$S='"$S"
```

It echoes:

```
anything
$S=
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your parentheticals are creating subshells, which don't affect the variables in the outer environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` has to execute in the current shell; you need to invert your pipeline.

```
read S < <(echo anything | tee >(gzip - > S.gz))
```

or, in `bash` 4.2 or later, use the `lastpipe` option. (Note that job control must be inactive for `lastpipe` to take effect. It is off by default in non-interactive shells, and can be turned off in interactive shells with `set +m`.)

```
shopt -s lastpipe
echo anything | tee >(gzip - > S.gz) | read S
```

Comment: `shopt` worked just fine for me (although the bashie `< <(` is much more undecifrable sexy...)